# API (accessible via jumpbox server) testing using JMeter

Tags: curl, jmeter, load-testing, ssh-tunnel

I need to load test an API that can be accessed only using a Jumpbox server. I am able to hit the API in my command prompt by ssh tunnelling and a curl command. I read so many articles, which says after I ssh tunnel, I should be able to hit the API using my Chrome browser. But unfortunately I can't. I get 403 error on Chrome, as well as on JMeter. Can anyone please help?
I have added the SSH command and the curl command that I used.

```
ssh -L 8801:qa.aws.test.com:8080 admin@jumpbox.aws.test.com
curl -XPOST "http://test.aws.test.com:8080/customers"  -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ "customer": "123456"}'
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong port.

`ssh -L 8801:qa.aws.test.com:8080` command instructs SSH client to listen on the port `8801` on your local machine and forward all traffic to port `8080` @ `qa.aws.test.com`

So you should use `http://localhost:8801/customers` URL in Chrome, JMeter, cURL or whatever.

- If you want to use cURL - there is `Import from cURL` JMeter dialog where you can put your command

  [image]
- If you want to use JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) - make sure to configure your browser to use proxy for local traffic as well
- You can also consider using [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/13354690351377-The-BlazeMeter-Chrome-Extension-Record-JMeter-Selenium-or-Synchronized-JMeter-and-Selenium), in this case you won't have to worry about proxies, SSL certificates and so on.